# For the space $X = T \# T$ find its fundamental group and prove the universal cover is contractible.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the task:

Let $X = T \# T$, the sum of $2$ tori identified by removing a small disk from each of them and gluing the missing disks along the boundary. Find the fundamental group of $X$, show the universal cover is contractible, and deduce that any image of $S^n$ into $X$ is contractible.

As for the first part i assume one should apply Van Kampen to the spaces of the Tori with a disk removed (so that the intersection is homotopically equivalent to the $S^1$ around the removed part). Now I think the torus with a disk removed is homotopically equivalent to a torus with a point removed, which is the wedge of two circles. But one of this circles is generated by the intersection in Van Kampen, so that one we consider to be a trivial loop. In the end Van Kampen gives us that $X$ has the fundamental group of $Z * Z$ which coincedentally is again the fundamental group of a wedge of two circles.

Now my understanding of Van Kampen is dubious at best, is this line of thinking correct? And how do i go about finding the universal cover? There's a hint to the second part of the task to look at covers of $X$ homotopically equivalent to a wedge product of circles, but I'm not sure how to even define such covers. How would one proceed with the rest of the task?

**As pointed out in the comments by multiple people:**

The original line of thinking about the fundamental group makes no sense and comes from a misinterpreted van Kampen. The proper answer given by the theorem is the group $<a,b,x,y| [a,b] = [x,y]>$.

**What remains is the part about the universal cover**

Comment: This sentence: "But one of this circles is generated by the intersection in Van Kampen, so that one we consider to be a trivial loop." is false, so the rest of your argument is wrong. If the two natural generators of the torus (the meridian and longitude) are called $a$ and $b$, then the boundary of the gluing circle is homotopic to $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Could you help clarify this for me: what you say makes sense when i look at the diagram of the torus, but since the fundamental group of the torus is abelian shouldnt the generators commute making $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ trivial?

Comment: In the sum construction, you've cut out part of the torus that is needed to make the generators of the fundamental group commute.

Comment: @RobArthan Right. So we cut out the part that lets the generators commute, but Van Kampen says that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is trivialized in the final group anyway? So is the answer to the question of fundamental group $(Z \times Z ) * (Z \times Z)$?

Comment: You have two spaces with fundamental group free on two generators (these are the punctured tori). The identification (based on @johnhughes comment) identifies the commutator in one of these free groups with the commuator in the other (here we're talking about commutators of generators). The fundamental group is then $\langle a,b,x,y\mid [a,b]=[x,y]\rangle$ by van Kampen.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks, I misunderstood what van Kampen does with the intersection but it makes sense now. Still have no idea about the cover part of the question.

Comment: If you know things like the uniformization theorem, then it's easy to see that the universal cover of a genus $g \geq 2$ surface is the hyperbolic plane, which is contractible.  Another way to see this is to realize the surface as a quotient of a certain polygon with edges identified in a certain way, and then "tile" the hyperbolic plane using the polygon by reflecting across its edges.

Answer (score 1):

The universal cover of $T \# T$ is a simply connected surface. It cannot be the sphere, so it has to be non-compact, and so its second homology is 0. Hence clearly all of its homologies are zero, and since it's simply connected, it's contractible by Whitehead's theorem.